# p5.js map() dynamically changing variable

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I have 2 questions revolving around the `blueHueDecrease` and `blueHueIncrease` variables below. What this code does is change the color of the background of the canvas with respect to the cursor's position on the canvas. This code is supposed to do three things: 1) have `blueHueDecrease` decrease from 255 to 0 from pixel position 0 to `width/2` on the canvas and have `blueHueIncrease` equal 0 throughout this range, 2) have `blueHueDecrease` and `blueHueIncrease` equal 0 at `width/2` on the canvas, and 3) have `blueHueDecrease` equal 0 from pixel position `width/2` to width on the canvas and `blueHueIncrease` increase from 0 to 255 within this range.

```js
var blueStartingValue;
var blueHueDecrease;
var blueHueIncrease;

function setup()
{
    createCanvas(800, 600);

    blueStartingValue = 255;
    blueHueDecrease = 0;
    blueHueIncrease = 0;  
}

function draw()
{
    blueHueDecrease = map(mouseX,0,width/2,blueStartingValue,0); //decreases blue from 255 to 0 within first half of canvas width
    blueHueIncrease = map(mouseX,width/2,width,blueHueDecrease,255); //increases blue from 0 to 255 within second half of canvas width, blueHueDecrease should equal 0 through out this range
    console.log("decrease: ",blueHueDecrease);
    console.log("increase: ",blueHueIncrease);
    background(0,0, max(blueHueDecrease,blueHueIncrease));
}
```

When I have the two lines from the setup function above as such:

```js
blueHueDecrease = map(mouseX,0,width/2,blueStartingValue,0); //decreases blue from 255 to 0 within first half of canvas width
blueHueIncrease = map(mouseX,width/2,width,blueHueDecrease,255); //increases blue from 0 to 255 within second half of canvas width, blueHueDecrease should equal 0 through out this range
```

`blueHueIncrease` is supposed to change values starting at `width/2`; instead, it has values through out the entire canvas width. Why is this? How do I constrain the mapped values for this variable between `width/2` and width?

When I set the boolean parameter in the map functions equal to true, to give:

```js
blueHueDecrease = map(mouseX,0,width/2,blueStartingValue,0,true); //decreases blue from 255 to 0 within first half of canvas width
blueHueIncrease = map(mouseX,width/2,width,blueHueDecrease,255,true); //increases blue from 0 to 255 within second half of canvas width, blueHueDecrease should equal 0 through out this range
```

`blueHueDecrease` gets limited between 0 and width/2 appropriately, but the `blueHueIncrease` doesn't get limited between width/2 and width; why is this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you post a simplified [mcve] that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I simplified the question and made it easier to read. Is it better now?

Comment: That's unclear. When `mouseX > width/2`, then `blueHueDecrease = 255` and `blueHueIncrease` is proper mapped to [0, 255]. When `mouseX < width/2`, then `blueHueDecrease` is mapped to [0, 255] and  `blueHueIncrease = blueHueDecrease`. That's what you've programmed.

Comment: @Rabbid76 blueHueDecrease = 0 for `width/2 > 0`, so that is mapped correctly, but blueHueIncrease = blueHueDecrease when `mouseX < width/2`; why is this? I could just do `blueHueIncrease = map(mouseX,width/2,width,0,255,true);` (without using blueHueDecrease) and blueHueIncrease would only have changing values when `mouseX > width/2`, but how can I map blueHueIncrease to only have values changing when `mouseX > width/2` using blueHueDecrease like in the question? If this isn't possible, why?

Comment: @hsivru `blueHueIncrease = blueHueDecrease` when `mouseX < width/2`, because `blueHueDecrease` is the lower bound in `map(mouseX,width/2,width,blueHueDecrease,255,true);` and in this case `blueHueIncrease` is restricted to the lower bound, because of the last parameter  (`true`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `mouseX > width/2`, then `blueHueDecrease = 255` and `blueHueIncrease` is proper mapped to [0, 255].

When `mouseX < width/2`, then `blueHueDecrease` is mapped to [0, 255] and `blueHueIncrease = blueHueDecrease`, because `blueHueDecrease` is the lower bound in

> ```js
> map(mouseX,width/2,width,blueHueDecrease,255,true);
> ```

and in this case of `mouseX < width/2`, `blueHueIncrease` is restricted to the lower bound, because of the last parameter in [`map`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/map) (`true`).

If you want to map `blueHueDecrease` when the mouse is left and `blueHueIncrease` when the mouse is right, then you`ve to:

```js
var blueHueDecrease = map(mouseX, 0, width/2, 255, 0, true); 
var blueHueIncrease = map(mouseX, width/2, width, 0, 255, true);
```

If you want to restrict the blue color to a minimum, then you've to use a different `blueStartingValue` and map from `blueStartingValue`  to 255, rather than from 0 to `blueStartingValue`:

```js
var blueStartingValue = 128;
var blueHueDecrease = map(mouseX, 0, width/2, 255, blueStartingValue, true); 
var blueHueIncrease = map(mouseX, width/2, width, blueStartingValue, 255, true);
```

See the example which demonstrates the different behavior:

```js
var blueStartingValue = 255;
var blueStartingValue3 = 128;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(400, 210);
}

function draw() {
    var blueHueDecrease = map(mouseX,0,width/2,blueStartingValue,0);
    var blueHueIncrease = map(mouseX,width/2,width,blueHueDecrease,255); 
    
    var blueHueDecrease2 = map(mouseX,0,width/2,blueStartingValue,0,true); 
    var blueHueIncrease2 = map(mouseX,width/2,width,blueHueDecrease2,255,true); 

    var blueHueDecrease3 = map(mouseX, 0, width/2, 255, 0, true); 
    var blueHueIncrease3 = map(mouseX, width/2, width, 0, 255, true); 

    var blueHueDecrease4 = map(mouseX, 0, width/2, 255, blueStartingValue3, true); 
    var blueHueIncrease4 = map(mouseX, width/2, width, blueStartingValue3, 255, true); 
    
    background(0);
    textSize(25);

    fill(0, 0, blueHueDecrease);
    rect(10, 10, 40, 40);
    fill(0, 0, blueHueIncrease);
    rect(60, 10, 40, 40);
    fill(255);
    text(`map(,,,, false)`, 110, 45);

    fill(0, 0, blueHueDecrease2);
    rect(10, 60, 40, 40);
    fill(0, 0, blueHueIncrease2);
    rect(60, 60, 40, 40);
    fill(255);
    text(`map(,,,, true)`, 110, 95);

    fill(0, 0, blueHueDecrease3);
    rect(10, 110, 40, 40);
    fill(0, 0, blueHueIncrease3);
    rect(60, 110, 40, 40);
    fill(255);
    text(`new approach`, 110, 145);

    fill(0, 0, blueHueDecrease4);
    rect(10, 160, 40, 40);
    fill(0, 0, blueHueIncrease4);
    rect(60, 160, 40, 40);
    fill(255);
    text(`start = ` + str(blueStartingValue3), 110, 195);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why doesn't `blueHueIncrease` reduce in hue at the same rate as `blueHueDecrease` from `[0,width/2]`? Why does `blueHueIncrease` reduce faster?